# Publishing ASP.NET Core+EF to Azure Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll'

Tags: entity-framework, azure, web-applications, asp.net-core, sqlclient

Publishing ASP.NET Core application with EF to Azure Web App results with this error when connecting SQL server:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method SearchDocumentsWebApp.Controllers.SearchApiController.SearchByTopic (SearchDocumentsWebApp) with arguments (info) - ModelState is Valid
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[8]
      The LINQ expression '[e].Id.Equals(__email_0, CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. To configure this warning use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API (event id 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning'). ConfigureWarnings can be used when overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationContextFactory[8]
      The LINQ expression 'SingleOrDefault()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. To configure this warning use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API (event id 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning'). ConfigureWarnings can be used when overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler[1]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
      System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize(IntPtr pmo)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor()
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
         at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize(IntPtr pmo)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action SearchDocumentsWebApp.Controllers.SearchApiController.SearchByTopic (SearchDocumentsWebApp) in 3176.7883ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize(IntPtr pmo)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at SearchDocumentsWebApp.Controllers.SearchApiController.<SearchByTopic>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\gubert\Source\Repos\Amdocs\SearchDocumentsWebApp\src\SearchDocumentsWebApp\Controllers\SearchAPIController.cs:line 76
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.RequestTrackingMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
```

here's my project.json:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect": "2.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.2-beta1",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.*.json",
      "LICENSE.txt"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
  "scripts": {
    //"prepublish": [ "npm install", "npm recompileapp" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "platform",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]

    }
  }
}
```

I even tried to change the "type" property of "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" to "platform" so it will copy it's dlls, also tried to copy "System.Data.SqlClient.dll" to /wwwroot/bin folder restarted the app but still get the same error.

on my local machine it works

Comment: huh. You're using ASP.NET Core 1.1 packages, but only targeting netcoreapp1.0`? also your versions are inconsistent. You use iis integration tools 1.1.0 but have 1.0.0-preview2 in your tools section

Comment: @Tseng Azure only supports the IIS tools at 1.00 at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

**SOLVED!**

azure web apps runs on windows 2012 r2, so I needed to set win7 runtimes and change publish settings to win7-x64:

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win7-x64": {}
  },
```

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted please, even if you answered it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I managed to tweak this to my scenario and got the code working. The above set up didn't work for me though - I had to ensure that I manually deleted all of the files on the site and THEN deployed using win7-x64